# Sourcetree not nesting features

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

On my private PC, I am having the problem, that sourcetree is not nesting my features correctly (see "953_wrong_text").

[image: wrong nesting]

But if I add a new feature on my working PC, everything is fine, see the correctly nested features. Also when clicking on Git-Flow, I get a sightly different window

[image: different window]

Is this a pure Sourcetree issue or did I do something wrong with this repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue follow the below steps.

repository->repository settings -> "edit config file..." and add replace below code with an existing one and Fixes the issue.

```
[gitflow "prefix"]
bugfix = bugfix/
feature = feature/
hotfix = hotfix/
release = release/
```

Reference URL: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Is-GitFlow-integration-broken-for-SourceTree-3-1-2/qaq-p/1039172